# Why is there a weird green-black glitch in my rendering?

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, eevee-render-engine, lighting

I'm trying to render my animation and now this green line pops up and changes the color of my model's outfit to all black and the green also appears on the stage model (picture below). I thought that it might've had something with me trying to reduce my render time but it's happened the last time I tried rendering this animation too when I didn't try to reduce my render time except the green line wasn't there. I also thought that maybe it wouldn't appear in the final result but it did...help? The only thing that I remember that I changed before the glitch started was the black lighting in front to white so that I could rid of scene world but I doubt that's the cause. My render engine is eevee.

Picture of the glitch, the one below it is how it's supposed to look like:
[image: Pic]

[image: Picture of what it's supposed to look like]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how it is supposed to look?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard I've edited it and added a picture for what it's supposed to look like at the bottom. I would do viewport rendering but last time I did that it ruined my bloom and/or emissive material and of course it has no solution..so yeah

Comment: OK, I would say that, especially because of the fuzzy white part on the spine where it looks like the original outfit is still there, there is a duplicate mesh exactly where the outfit is, and it’s fighting with the real outfit for which one goes in front. Check for that.

Comment: if Zarguls answer doesn't help (but i think it will) please provide blend file.